# Microsoft will Not Let Me Close The Account Without My Phone Number

Tags: outlook.com, microsoft-account

I am trying to close my Microsoft Account, so I went to [How to close your Microsoft account](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12412/microsoft-account-how-to-close-account).

Then I Clicked [Close your account](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=523898).

It asked for my login and password which I provided.

Then it shows -

[image]

I Clicked Next. Then it is saying

[image]

I was looking for their support email so that I can request to delete my account without providing my phone number. Even [the bot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/contactus/) will not help me without providing my phone number.

I also tried to login to their [forum](https://social.microsoft.com/). It also does not let me login without the phone number.

What to do now?

How can I delete my account without providing my phone number?